# Convert maven plugin exec-maven-plugin to gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I need to use below maven plugin in gradle project. Please give some idea how to convert in gradle?

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>main</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>make</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>test</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.service.main.TWAService</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Please give some idea how i can do in gradle.

Answer (score 1):

```
task runTwaService(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.service.main.TWAService'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: from this task i need to send to make file. how i can do?

Comment: To invoke a `main` method in a java class, use [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html). To invoke a process from the command line (eg `make`) then use an [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task